# http2 in node.js, express, socket.io client

Tags: node.js, express, http, socket.io, http2

I am building a web app that uses a express and node.js in the backend. In my `server.js` file, I have the following code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
```

I recently discovered that there is http2 available, should I change the line 3 to
`const server = require("http2").Server(app);` instead?

If I switch to http2, is there anything else I need to specifically change that wasn't present in http1? And is the way of sending HTTP requests such as get or post any different from http1 to http2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP2 is more efficient and loads faster pages-[Differences](https://medium.com/@factoryhr/http-2-the-difference-between-http-1-1-benefits-and-how-to-use-it-38094fa0e95b).
But I suggest you use https since its more secure and most of the browsers mark non https requests as insecure.
[similar stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488601/what-is-difference-between-https-and-http-2)

Comment: ok, so I would have `const server = require("http").Server(app);`

Comment: For development use `http` but for production I recommend using `https`. Also if this 
reply answers your question than you can mark it as _accepted_ answer.